# Rickshaw : data for multiple series not working

Tags: php, javascript, charts, d3.js, rickshaw

I'm trying to create some charts using [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/), importing the data with ajax generated in php.

If I use static datas, the chart displays;
If I copy/paste the data generated in the php (from a console/log()), the chart displays;
If I try to put the datas into a variable, and use that var in the js, it just doesnt' work. :(

This is my console log of what I get from the .php :
(As I said, if I copy paste that block of code into the .js substituting the "dataOutEvo" var, the graph displays as it should. So, I don't think the data is the problem.

```
[
        {
            name: "ligne",
            data: [{x:0,y:35},{x:1,y:34},{x:2,y:36},{x:3,y:35},{x:4,y:40},{x:5,y:35},{x:6,y:37},{x:7,y:40},{x:8,y:45},{x:9,y:46},{x:10,y:55},{x:11,y:63},{x:12,y:61},{x:13,y:45},{x:14,y:48},{x:15,y:49},{x:16,y:45},{x:17,y:44},{x:18,y:52},{x:19,y:43},{x:20,y:37},{x:21,y:36},{x:22,y:37},{x:23,y:34}],
            color: palette.color()
        },
        {
            name: "ligne",
            data: [{x:0,y:10},{x:1,y:15},{x:2,y:13},{x:3,y:15},{x:4,y:14},{x:5,y:16},{x:6,y:17},{x:7,y:25},{x:8,y:23},{x:9,y:24},{x:10,y:25},{x:11,y:28},{x:12,y:27},{x:13,y:21},{x:14,y:23},{x:15,y:19},{x:16,y:18},{x:17,y:16},{x:18,y:15},{x:19,y:14},{x:20,y:15},{x:21,y:16},{x:22,y:15},{x:23,y:16}],
            color: palette.color()
        },
        {
            name: "ligne",
            data: [{x:0,y:45},{x:1,y:49},{x:2,y:49},{x:3,y:50},{x:4,y:54},{x:5,y:51},{x:6,y:54},{x:7,y:65},{x:8,y:68},{x:9,y:70},{x:10,y:80},{x:11,y:91},{x:12,y:88},{x:13,y:66},{x:14,y:71},{x:15,y:68},{x:16,y:63},{x:17,y:60},{x:18,y:67},{x:19,y:57},{x:20,y:52},{x:21,y:52},{x:22,y:52},{x:23,y:50}],
            color: palette.color()
        },
        {
            name: "ligne",
            data: [{x:0,y:10},{x:1,y:15},{x:2,y:12},{x:3,y:5},{x:4,y:9},{x:5,y:15},{x:6,y:45},{x:7,y:125},{x:8,y:345},{x:9,y:256},{x:10,y:312},{x:11,y:345},{x:12,y:299},{x:13,y:165},{x:14,y:354},{x:15,y:368},{x:16,y:254},{x:17,y:213},{x:18,y:312},{x:19,y:165},{x:20,y:54},{x:21,y:32},{x:22,y:10},{x:23,y:5}],
            color: palette.color()
        },
        {
            name: "ligne",
            data: [{x:0,y:2},{x:1,y:3},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:1},{x:4,y:1},{x:5,y:2},{x:6,y:3},{x:7,y:15},{x:8,y:45},{x:9,y:27},{x:10,y:40},{x:11,y:42},{x:12,y:35},{x:13,y:18},{x:14,y:42},{x:15,y:40},{x:16,y:30},{x:17,y:25},{x:18,y:40},{x:19,y:20},{x:20,y:6},{x:21,y:4},{x:22,y:2},{x:23,y:1}],
            color: palette.color()
        }
        ]
```

And this is the js where something goes wrong :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $.ajax({    
    url: 'dataOutEvo.php', //le fichier qui va nous fournir la réponse      
    success: function(data) {    
        var dataOutEvo = data;
         console.log(dataOutEvo);
        var palette = new Rickshaw.Color.Palette( { scheme: 'spectrum2001' } );
        var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
          element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
          width: 960,
          height: 260,
          renderer: 'line',
          series:  dataOutEvo
        });

        graph.render();

        }
  });

});
```

Could anyone tell me what goes wrong ? Thank you :) Mathieu

---

I'm asking myself now if I shouldn't go another way, using this:

```
$fp = fopen('dataoutevo.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($js));
fclose($fp);
```

And this :

```
var palette = new Rickshaw.Color.Palette();
new Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax( {

  element: document.getElementById("chart"),
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
  renderer: 'line',
  dataURL: 'dataoutevo.json',
  onData: function(d) {
    Rickshaw.Series.zeroFill(d);
    return d;
  },
  onComplete: function(transport) {
    var graph = transport.graph;
    var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({  graph: graph  }); 
  } 

  } );
```

But it's is still not working … Does anyone can help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more what you mean when you say-

_If I try to put the datas into a variable, and use that var in the js, it just doesnt' work_

and then when you go on to say

_if I copy paste that block of code into the .js substituting the "dataOutEvo" var, the graph displays as it should)_
?

I just [**fiddled**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/Ar6BS/) your code with hard-coded data and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using your first implementation should work fine. I think your problem is when you call:

```
success: function(data) {
```

The data variable returned from PHP is actually a string (You can check this using the Javascript function) -

```
console.log(typeof(data));
```

On your PHP code you should be returning an (Associative) Array and make sure you're using the json_encode() function -

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

And on your JS side cast your returned data using the JSON.parse method -

```
var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your first implementation, add a dataType to the ajax call.

This should work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $.ajax({    
    url: 'dataOutEvo.php', //le fichier qui va nous fournir la réponse
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {    
        var dataOutEvo = data;
        console.log(dataOutEvo);
        var palette = new Rickshaw.Color.Palette( { scheme: 'spectrum2001' } );
        var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
          element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
          width: 960,
          height: 260,
          renderer: 'line',
          series:  dataOutEvo
        });
        graph.render();
        }
    });
});
```

> Notice the **dataType: 'json'** in the $.ajax call.

According to the JQuery documentation, adding the **json** dataType,

> Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The
>   JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected
>   and a parse error is thrown